# Spark SQL Foward Looking Range Between Interval

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that has user_id, date, and value. I'm getting a three day average of the value, per user, using the following block of code:

```
spark.sql(
"""SELECT *, mean(value) OVER (
   PARTITION BY user_id
   ORDER BY CAST(date AS timestamp)
   RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 2 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
   ) as mean FROM table1""")
```

I'd also like to get a forward-looking three day average. Basically the same code as above with the following tweaks

```
RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL CURRENT ROW AND 2 DAYS AFTER
```

I've played around with this a bit and done some googling but can't seem to find the right syntax for this. I've also tried using a negative preceding days, which ran without error, but returned all null values for the mean.

Any idea what the correct syntax is here?

EDIT:

Solution

`BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL 2 DAYS FOLLOWING`

Comment: BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL 2 DAYS FOLLOWING ?

Answer (score 0):

BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL 2 DAYS FOLLOWING

Thanks to Ponder Stibbons, who answered this in the comments